# Installation problems with Lilypond for Windows

Tags: windows, installation, ghostscript, lilypond

I am trying to install the latest stable version for Lilypond on windows 10.

My install dir is on the d: drive (not on the c: drive and I guess that the fonts are installed elsewhere.  If I compile a very small .ly file without any text in it, just notes, then it gets so far that I end up with a temp file which is a plain PostScript file.  No .pdf is made.  But I manage then to convert it using a Ghostscript (another one as the Ghostscript installed by Lilypond) that is on my drive and it can convert a .pdf out of the PostScript rendered by Lilypond.

However, when I compile a the test file that comes with the installation, I have a lot of complaints.  See below.  Only a temp file is made which is crippled, it even does not end with the classical EOF of PostScript.

when trying to convert that crippled version anyway, I get mysterious messages about not finding the font files like:

Unknown in Prolog section at line 34:
%%Title: (FontSet/C059-Roman)

I am at a loss.

When I try to install Lilypond on my c: drive, then it refuses to run and I presume that is because I choose the d: drive as the drive on which the installationdir must be positioned.

Here below is the log of my test.ly

## -*-compilation-*-

Processing `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log'
Parsing...
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:1:2: error: GUILE signaled an error for the expression beginning here

-*-compilation-*-

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:2:12: error: undefined character or shorthand: `Processing` C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.ly'

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:2:12: error: syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting '.' or '='
Processing
`C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.ly'

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:2:42: error: syntax error, unexpected ''', expecting '='
Processing `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.ly
'

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:9:15: error: undefined character or shorthand: `Converting to` /Users/User/Desktop/test.pdf'...

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:9:44: error: syntax error, unexpected ''', expecting '='
Converting to `/Users/User/Desktop/test.pdf
'...

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.log:1: warning: no \version statement found, please add

\version "2.22.0"

for future compatibility
fatal error: failed files: "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.log"

Answer (score 0):

Still having the problem?

Try uninstalling all LilyPond software, on C drive and D, then reinstalling.

I suspect the strange compiling of the test.ly has to do with character sets and may be ignored.

Do you get any errors or warnings when you compile something like:

```
\version "2.22.0"

{ c' c' c' c' }
```

Can you post them?

I'm wondering if you other GhostScript program is interfering with LilyPond.  Do you have a way of disabling it temporarily? Or put it farther down the PATH than LilyPond.

Comment: I put the PATH to LilyPond first in my path statements.

I tried to compile your suggestion.  The log does not give complaints, and your tryout source code was transformed in a temp file which contained PostScript code and I conversed  that with my original ghostscript interpreter tp .pdf file format.  Everything went fine, no complaints and beautiful output!  I did other experiments, and PostScript files seem to be always created fine if there are no Latin letters printed.

I am trying to find the gs executable in order to rename it, but I do not manage to find it.

Comment: To find an executable in Windows, start a command shell (terminal) and type `where executable_name`, so in your case I think it would be `where gs`.